# Screeching, distorting and oversensitive AirPods Pro

Tags: audio, airpods

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask, but after googling hours and trying out ideas without any vein I'm here.

A few weeks ago my Airpod Pro upgraded to the newest firmware. After the upgrade the right airpod had some screeching voice, as if there were certain frequencies it overamplifies. I kind of could live with it. I put it away for almost a week due to vacation.

When I came back from vacation the right side worked perfectly, but the left side got way worst than the right side ever been. Now, when I put the left one in my left ear it amplifies how my vein beats in my ear. It seems it amplifies even the smallest movement in my ear while I'm talking. It distorts everything.

I know putting aside these Airpods for 2 weeks might provide some solution, as it happened first time. :) But, I'm not a Roman and Airpods are not cabbage.

I haven't found any guide how to reinstall firmware.

Beside call Apple support I don't know what to do. Calling them doesn't seem good solution because it is, seemingly, software problem.

I would appreciate any help or thoughts.

Comment: I had similar issues, I just had them replaced. Apple will repair them for free according to this https://support.apple.com/airpods-pro-service-program-sound-issues

Comment: @RusI That is correct! I had mine replaced a few months ago. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I've had what sounds like this problem before, on a previous firmware, and I resolved it by placing them in the case (on charge, I don't know if that made a difference) for at least 5 minutes.

You can't reinstall or downgrade the firmware, but you can try resetting your AirPods Pro.

1. Place AirPods Pro in the case and close the lid.
2. Wait a couple of seconds, then open the lid.
3. Hold the button on the case. The light on the front will start flashing white.
4. Keep holding the button on the case. The light will go orange. Let go of the button.
5. Move iPhone near AirPods and tap to Connect.

Comment: Thank you @grg, unfortunately it doesn't help. The pain is that, there is no other suggestion across internet about how to fix it.